# In Android, is there any way to retrieve the call forwarding number on GSM phones?

Tags: android, gsm, forwarding

Since GSM phones have a separate call settings screen for call forwarding (and those settings, I believe, are stored on the SIM card), is there a way to retrieve the call forwarding info programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able do to that via the 'com.android.internal.telephony.phone' class. You can't import it directly in Eclipse and you will have to use Reflection to use that private API.
Be warned: This API might work differently across a wide variety of phones as it's not intended to be used in non-system applications.

I just found this thread, it might give you a clue. 
http://www.anddev.org/post52643.html?hilit=incoming%20call#p52643

Comment: I don't see anything in ITelephony that has anything to do with forwarding, so why do I need to import that interface? And in the Phone class, it looks like the forwarding uses a callback whcih then receives the forwarding info. How would I gou about doing that via reflection?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that.. I'm not really experienced with using private APIs, just took a quick peek at that class and found some forwarding related stuff, so I just posted it here.